# What are key differences between InputNotebook and EvaluationNotebook?

Tags: evaluation, notebooks, files-and-directories

I am still new to Mathematica but advancing to a point of programming notebook and cell manipulations using native commands. Sometimes they call for specifying `InputeNotebook[]` while at other times they call for `EvaluationNotebook[]`. What are their key differences?

If I am only working with a single open notebook which type do I have?

If my current open notebook is `notebook.nb` and wish to load a function saved to `function.nb` which type are they?

If I am unsure of which type I have which is the safest to use?

Comment: In your case you can use both. The second one is useful when the UI, e.g. Button is a part of a palette. Then in context of evaluation that happens after pressing the button the EvalNb is the palette and the InputNb is the 'regular' notebook that is selected/active.